# Parsing date with Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm parsing a json file using Jackson like the one below :

```
    {
      "start_time": "2013/10/15 15:16:39",
      "name" : "Kapil"
    }
```

My code to parse the file is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
mapper.setDateFormat(myDateFormat);
JsonNode newNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
```

I'm then storing the JsonNode object in MongoDB and performing a range query on the date. 
My newNode object looks like this :

```
{"start_time":"2013/10/15 15:16:39","name":"Kapil"}
```

I'm afraid that Jackson is interpreting the start_time field as a string rather than a date and hence my range query on the date is not working. How do I get Jackson to interpret the date type correctly?

Comment: Are you grabbing the value of "start_time" as a String, then parsing it as Date?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes. I'm grabbing it's value as a string. Jackson should parse it as a date after the above settings right?

Comment: is there an error you're getting when parsing? Or are you able to parse it and store into the database but just not as a date type?

Comment: There's no error when I'm parsing, it just doesn't store it as a date datatype.